# JOIN INNER. Psycopg2. Python

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

У меня есть две таблицы: old_prod и new_prod. В обоих есть поле price и prod_id.

Задача: если price из new_prod на 20% меньше чем в old_prod занести целую запись(category, link, price) в третью таблицу good_prod. Из общего у двух товаров - prod_id

Подскажите как это можно сделать одним запросом к БД без вмешательства питона? Спасибо.

Comment: *если price из new_prod на 20% меньше чем в old_prod* Угу... и по какому признаку определять, какую запись с какой следует сравнивать?

Comment: Akina, виноват, исправился.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
INSERT INTO good_prod (category, link, price)
SELECT ???.category, ???.link, ???.price
FROM new_prod
JOIN old_prod USING (prod_id)
WHERE new_prod.price <= old_prod.price * 0.8
;
```

Поскольку непонятно, из какой таблицы брать значения, поставил знаки вопроса. Нужные алиасы расставляй самостоятельно.

Запрос предполагает, что в обеих таблицах поле `prod_id` как минимум уникально.